# Tracking Growth of a Metric over Time In TimescaleDB

Tags: sql, postgresql, timescaledb

I'm currently running timescaleDB. I have a table that looks similar to the following

```
        one_day        | name | metric_value 
------------------------+---------------------
2022-05-30 00:00:00+00 | foo  |    400
2022-05-30 00:00:00+00 | bar  |    200
2022-06-01 00:00:00+00 | foo  |    800
2022-06-01 00:00:00+00 | bar  |    1000
```

I'd like a query that returns the % growth and raw growth of metric, so something like the following.

```
 name | % growth | growth 
-------------------------
 foo  |  200%    | 400
 bar  |  500%    | 800
```

I'm fairly new to timescaleDB and not sure what the most efficient way to do this is. I've tried using LAG, but the main problem I'm facing with that is `OVER (GROUP BY time, url)` doesn't respect that I ONLY want to consider the same name in the group by and can't seem to get around it. The query works fine for a single name.

Thanks!

Comment: try OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY one_day)

Comment: also growth from 400 to 800 is not 200%, it is 100%

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use LAG to get the previous value for the same name using the PARTITION option:

```
lag(metric_value,1,0) over (partition by name order by one_day)
```

This says, when ordered by 'one_day', within each 'name', give me the previous (the second parameter to LAG says 1 row) value of 'metric_value'; if there is no previous row, give me '0'.